# How do I fix a "Error: Could not determine an upstream remote name!" from Terminal?

Tags: git

Whenever I attempt to commit changes to a file in VScode it gives me a "Error: Could not determine an upstream remote name!" error when "updating self-published (nightly) versions"

I truthfully have no idea what this error means since I've never seen it before or seen it mentioned anywhere. I attempted to switch directories, check that everything was set up properly (and to my knowledge it seems to look alright). I wish I could say more but I have no idea what any of this means. If you need any more information please ask and I will try to be of help.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you've tried to run `git push` and didn't work. From what I'm reading, it seems your computer doesn't have a default upstream and is attempting to push to an unknown one which is returning this error. If you haven't, then in your console type `git push -u origin main`. The `-u` will prevent the need to type `origin main` for every subsequent push. After the initial push, `git push` will work to push commits to the repository.

Comment: From what I can tell the issue arises when commiting the changes, not pushing them. It fails when I run `git commit -m "Something"`